# Propagate action from nested component to AppController

Tags: ember.js

I have a component nested several levels down in other components. I'm trying to propagate an action all the way up to the `AppController` in order to open a modal.

The only way I know of doing this is to pass in the action to each component - but this seems extremely impractical. Is there a better way to access the `AppController` from a nested component?

[See my jsbin for the code](http://jsbin.com/jovagoyoja/4/edit)

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.AppController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        openModal: function(){
            alert('this would open the modal')
        }
    }
})

App.MainComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({})

App.SubComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        triggerModal: function(){
            // need to trigger the openModal action on the AppController
            this.sendAction('openModal')

        }
    }
})
```

.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h1>Index</h1>

{{main-component model=model}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/main-component">
  <h2>Main component</h2>

{{#each color in model}}
    {{sub-component color=color}}
{{/each}}
</script>   

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/sub-component">
  <button {{action "triggerModal"}}>{{color}}</button>
</script>
```

EDIT: I'm aware that I can render a template into the modal outlet:

```
this.render(modalName, {
  into: 'application',
  outlet: 'modal'
});
```

But I'm trying to access an action on the `AppController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [Ember.Instrumentation module](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html), which can be used like a pub/sub.
Here is [a working JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/maroje/6/edit?html,js,output).

Solution outline:
1. On `ApplicationController` init, the controller subscribes to `"openModal"` event.
2. The neseted component instruments the event `"openModal"` within an action.
3. The instrumentation can be executed with a payload, so this would be the place to determine the modal content.

```js
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(options) {
      alert('this would open the modal with the content: ' + options.modalContent);
    }
  },
  subscribeEvents: function() {
    this.set('openModalSubscriber', Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe('openModal', {
      before: Ember.K,
      after: Ember.run.bind(this, function(name, timestamp, payload, beforeRet) {
        this.send('openModal', payload);
      }),
    }, this));
  }.on('init')
});
```

```js
App.SubComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    triggerModal: function() {
      Ember.Instrumentation.instrument('openModal.sub-component', {
        modalContent: 'Inner content of modal'
      }, Ember.K, this);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but isn't the instrument module primarily for performance testing?

Comment: Yes it does. But I don't see any reason why not utilizing it as a pub/sub.

Answer (score 0):

Components are supposed to be pretty isolated, therefore it probably doesn't make sense to be jumping over other components, going straight to their controllers... See the following discussion [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/sendaction-on-stack-components-controller-actions/3332)

There is a `targetObject` property, which might be of use to you, although I am not 100% sure what you would set it to in this case.